# Jenkins Log Parser rule to exclude text between two strings

Tags: regex, jenkins, continuous-integration, logparser

I'm using [Jenkins log parser plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) to parse the console for errors. I'm trying to create a rule to **OK** a block of text between two strings without raising any flag.

I know `ok /abc.*xyz/` rule works for single line.How do I extend this to a block of text or multiple lines like:
**For example:**

> abc
>   ... ...
>   ... ...
>   ... ...
>   xyz
>   **Note:** "xyz" is the first string that's matched after "abc"

I tried `ok /abc(?s)(.*?)xyz/` but was unable to make it work.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should works:

```
/abc([\S\s]*)xyz/g
```

That will give you the data between `abc` and `xyz`.

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/vC5xC2/2)

I think you can use it like this:

```
${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="(?i)abc[\\S\\s]xyz", showTruncatedLines=false}
```

Comment: It didn't help.Not sure how jenkins log parser plugin works internally but I tried different regex expressions but no luck as far as multiple lines is concerned. I also tried `/abc(\s)(.*?)xyz/s` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC5xC2/3) but to no avail.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26125156/4519059) can help to use regex in jenkins;).